# PHP runtime exception

Tags: php, runtime

A website my friend owns is experiencing an issue and doesn't load anymore, I'm trying to assist but don't know a lot about PHP and websites.

The error that comes up when the page is opened is

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message
>   'JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_APPLICATION_LOAD' in
>   /home/vandlar1/public_html/libraries/cms/application/cms.php:329 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   /home/vandlar1/public_html/libraries/joomla/factory.php(124):
>   JApplicationCms::getInstance('site') #1
>   /home/vandlar1/public_html/index.php(38):
>   JFactory::getApplication('site') #2 {main} thrown in
>   /home/vandlar1/public_html/libraries/cms/application/cms.php on line
>   329

In the PHP file that it refers to this is the function

```
public static function getInstance($name = null)
    {
        if (empty(static::$instances[$name]))
        {
        // Create a JApplicationCms object.
        $classname = 'JApplication' . ucfirst($name);

        if (!class_exists($classname))
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(JText::sprintf('JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_APPLICATION_LOAD', $name), 500);
        }

        static::$instances[$name] = new $classname;
    }

    return static::$instances[$name];
}
```

I haven't dealt with run time errors in my experience much so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why in the world is the argument `$name` optional (defaultet to null) if all the code in the the method requires it to be set? But that might be Joomla-code?

Comment: I'm not sure, it's code from a go daddy website.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about Joomla, but it looks like this function is trying to find a class called `JApplicationSite` and is failing to find it. It could be an autoloading problem, i.e. the application doesn't know where to look for the file/class. Or it could be that the class doesn't exist.

Comment: The first error I ran into was this: Warning: require_once(/home/vandlar1/public_html/libraries/cms.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vandlar1/public_html/includes/framework.php on line 44

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/vandlar1/public_html/libraries/cms.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/vandlar1/public_html/includes/framework.php on line 44  In the framwork.php at that line it is trying to bootstrap the cms libraries in the cms directory.

Comment: The problem I saw was there is no cms.php in the libraries directory but there is one in the libraries/cms/application so i extended the path to that file and that caused the runtime exception.

Comment: This might help: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2728703 Looks like others are getting this problem after upgrading from Joomla 1.7 to 2.5 when using an older version of PHP. Not sure if you/your friend has attempted to upgrade or note?

Comment: I see that, the joomla the site is using is 3.2.3 and when I try to update it it says that the server doesn't meet the requirements.The PHP version is 5.5.  As far as them trying to update the jooma they haven't but doesn't know if it would have tried to do so automatically.